# How can I get rq structure in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

I made a linux module program to get rq structure in CPU like this

```
    #include <linux/init.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <../kernel/sched/sched.h>

    int init_hello(void)
    {
        int cpu;

        for_each_online_cpu(cpu)
        {
            struct rq *rq = cpu_rq(cpu)
            printk( KERN_ALERT "rq->curr->pid = %d", rq->curr->pid);
        }
    }
    ...
```

Both 'Makefile' and 'insmod hello.ko' are done, But I got a error message like this

```
    ...
    [30557.012624] hello: Unknown symbol runqueues (err 0)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question? I need to do the same thing.